# Intellij automatically converting FQN to imports

Tags: intellij-idea

If I have code that has a bunch of fully qualified names in it (java.util.List, javax.swing.JLabel, etc.) is there a command in intellij that will automatically convert those to import the package and just use the class name?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This can be achieved by first turning on inspection for this.

Open up the `Settings` dialog and go down to Inspections and then search for `qualified` keyword and then turn on `Unnecessary fully qualified name` inspection:

[image]

That will make all occurrences of FQN in the code being color marked:

[image]

Now place the cursor on one of the highlighted areas and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and a popup will give you the choice to `Fix all 'Unnecessary fully qualified name' problems`:

[image]

And then all FQN's will have been replaced with imports at the top instead:

[image]

If you want to run this inspection on the whole project (instead of just the current file) then you can choose the `Run inspection on...` alternative in the context menu:

[image]

Then choose `Whole project`:

[image]

And then finally in the `Inspection Results` window choose to `Apply Fix` on the selection:

[image]

Comment: Run inspection on... what a killer feature. Saved a botched Structured Search and Replace. Nice.

Comment: If you have some time it would be helpful to update the screenshots as IntelliJ has changed a little since your answer. Anyways, still helpful!

Answer (score 11):

In case, for new code entries if you are seeing the FQNs, just make sure that **Use fully qualified class names** is **un-checked**.

```
Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Use fully qualified class names
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this should be marked as answer as it aligns with new UI