# Quick fix all intention errors

Tags: intellij-idea

As of now I am pressing alt + enter per intention fix in my source code.

Sometimes I have a lot of the same issues in a file and I'm wondering if a quick fix can be done for a whole package or source file.

Screenshot

[image: Intellij Intention]

Thanks

Comment: I think you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17038349/1350762). It will explain how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Maba!!! You could put an answer though and get some points :) (or mark this as duplicate)

Comment: Well that answer I linked to is mine so you are free to give it an upvote ;-)

Comment: There is also a way to apply fixes to the whole project as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74811245/5118762

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There should be a "fix all" option in the sub-menu (if you're navigating via keyboard, just press the "right" arrow key to get the sub-menu then select the fix all option).

[image]

Comment: too bad this is not for all kind of errors, like removing unused variables..