# How to apply "quick fix" to multiple errors at once in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, pressing `Alt+Enter` on an error pops up a dialog that shows a fix which gets applied when you press `Enter`. Is there a way to do that action on multiple errors of the same type in the a file?

Answer (score 31):

First press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>→</kbd>, select *Fix all 'xxx' problems in File*, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Here's what it should look like:

[image: Clarifying screen shot]

Comment: There’s no option to hit →. The errors I’m trying to fix is if a Java local variable inside an inner class is not declared as final and I have multiple of those errors in the class file.

Comment: For some problems this solution is the best thing ever! Unfortunately this can't be used for different errors.

Comment: As alternative, also check out the "Code Cleanup..." features to apply quick fix: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-problems.html#auto-quick-fix

Comment: @Glide Re: "There’s no option to hit →".  Bas means, hit the right-arrow key on your keyboard

Answer (score 4):

There is even a way to fix warnings across the whole project or a selected scope (I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 Ultimate).

Navigate via `Code -> Inspect Code...`
to the following Inspection dialog.

[image]

Specify your scope and hit *Analyze.*

In the tab that pops up you can navigate to you specific warning and fix all with one button click.
Here is an example for replacing explicit types with the `var` keyword.

[image]

Clicking the *Replace explicit type with 'var'* replaces all occurrence in the defined scope.

Comment: Also note: In the bottom panel you can actually highlight over all of the files by selecting the first one, then holding ALT and clicking the last one. Then you can press the yellow button and it will apply the fix to all of the files at once!! Super helpful

Answer (score 1):

On Mac,  <kbd>⌥</kbd>  +  <kbd>↵</kbd>  (*Option* + *Enter*)