# Automatically move full package names from java code into imports for intelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We have some auto-generated code files that have the fully qualified package names in all the references. I.e.

```
void foo(java.util.Collection bars);
```

Instead, I'd like to automatically move `java.util.Collection` to the import statements, and just have:

```
void foo(Collection bars);
```

I have done this manually in the past with some text-replacements, but I'd like it if it could automatically be done. Does intelliJ offer this feature?

Edit: I was about to find a duplicate question with the appropriate answer [Intellij automatically converting FQN to imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033585/intellij-automatically-converting-fqn-to-imports). I'm going to close this.

Comment: Do you have a class defined as `Collection` somewhere in your project?

Comment: No. Why does that matter? I just gave a random example, but there's also lots of instances of our own classes being written with a full path in the code.

Comment: That's the only reason that I can think of that IntelliJ would use the fully qualified class name there.  What options do Alt + Return (or Option + Return) give you?

Comment: Maybe `Settings` > `Editor` > `Auto Import` > `Optimize imports on the fly` would help?

Comment: @Makoto alt+return seems to give the "replace qualified name with import" which is exactly what I'm looking for! Any way I can just have this scan an run on the whole class? The class was generated by some other tool. I've just inherited the class in this state

Comment: I don't know if there's a good way to do it for the entire class offhand.

Comment: You can go to `Analyze` > `Run Inspection by Name` and type "Unnecessary fully qualified name" to run the inspection for a whole project.